# Android copy sqlite database from pc to device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, adb, root

I want to use a database I have on my pc in my android project. To archive that, I have to copy the database into the /data/data/xxx.xxx.xxx/databases folder. How can I do that? I read of using adb but I think you require root to access the /data/data folder. Is there any other way to copy the database into the app data folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place our database in `assets` folder in your project and call the below method.

```
     public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
             String package_name=context.getPackageName();
             String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"+package_name+"/databases/";
             String DB_NAME = "your_database_file_name";
            try {
                InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

                File dbFile=new File(DB_PATH);
                dbFile.mkdirs();

                String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;

                while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `File dbFile=new dbFile(DB_PATH);` be `File dbFile=new File(DB_PATH);` ?

Comment: You are right, updated the answer Please have a look.